# Conditional appending items from a list into multiple documents

Tags: python, list, append, conditional-statements, doc

I am pretty new to python. My question is related to appending data based on `index[0]` into a set of documents (e.g. doc1,doc2).

```
g = [('elsiescdesign', 'flowers', 6),('elsiescdesign', 'running', 6), ('fulviomeloni', 'flowers', 1), ('connor-burrows', 'flowers', 1), ('withoutroots', 'flowers', 1), ('thegreenraven', 'flowers', 2), ('taylor-music', 'flowers', 2), ('eda11y', 'flower', 7), ('2liice', 'flower', 1)]
```

Above is the sample data: `[(blogger,tag,countsoftagusedbyblooger)]`

I want to append all the bloggers tags into a document each e.g.

```
elsiescdesign =['flowers','flowers','flowers','flowers','flowers','flowers','running','running','running','running','running','running']
```

But not just for one bloggers, all the bloggers here. The reason for this is so that I can build my topic model.

Comment: you may need to group the result by blogger in a dict too

Comment: Yes, exactly my purpose! However, unsure how to code it out. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
bloggers = {}
for b in g:
    bloggers.setdefault(b[0], []).extend([b[1]] * b[2])
```

Comment: Thank you!! Works like a charm :D